# Unable to perform database CURD operations using dropwizard, hibernate, JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dropwizard

Actually i am finding best way to design data model for one of web service. I have three level of relationship. Currently unable to perform database operation with below data model.

> Track has one or more Transition Set and Each Transition Set having one or more transition metadata detail.

I made data model as below. I hope i developed data model correctly.

```
 - Track
  - ID
  - Title
  - Artist
  - [Other detail fields]
 - Transition Set
  - ID
  - Track ID
 - Transition Metadata
  - ID
  - Transition Set ID
  - [Other detail Fields]
```

Implemented this but having issues about database operation and getting only first transition only.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tracks")
public class Track
{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "trackSeq", sequenceName = "seq_tracks_id", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "trackSeq")
    private long id;

    // Other fields

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = TransitionMetadata.class)
    @JsonProperty
    @JoinTable(name = "transition_set", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "track_id", referencedColumnName = "id",
    table = "tracks") }, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "transition_set_id",
    table = "transition_metadata"))
    private List<TransitionMetadata> transitions = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "transition_set")
public class TransitionSet
{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "transitionSetSeq", sequenceName = "seq_transition_set_id", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "transitionSetSeq")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "track_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Track track;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "transition_metadata")
public class TransitionMetadata
{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "transitionMetadataSeq", sequenceName = "seq_transition_metadata_id", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "transitionMetadataSeq")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "transition_set_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private TransitionSet transitionSet;

    // Other fields
}
```

Looks like i am stuck here, can you please help me to figure out stuff.

Comment: I didn't read all your code, but inside `Tack` mapping, in the `targetEntity` of one-to-many relation you are writting `TransitionMetadata.class`, it should be `TransitionSet.class`, because Track doesn't has `TransitionMetadata` instead it has `TransitionSet, change also the parametrized type of list to TransitionSet.

Comment: thanks, i tried it but no luck, getting "cloud.dropwizard.otto.resources.TrackResource: could not extract ResultSet" error at deployment time.

Comment: Guys, Finally i got solution by this SO question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351524/unable-to-find-column-with-logical-name

Comment: Glad for hearing that :)

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill i am getting null issue like "SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: null value in column "transition_set_id" violates not-null constraint
web_1 |   Detail" .

Comment: That means you have not-null constraint in your schema for some fields, check your code, these fields shouldn't be null.

Comment: thanks, Actually it's foreign key column, It's now fixed by using "@JsonManagedReference" and "@JsonBackReference" annotations.