# JPA one to one with non primary key gives Unable to find column with logical name error

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, entity

I am designing entity of currency pair table with springboot + jpa  + hibernate. Database is postgres. Schema is as follows -

DDL of currency

```
CREATE TABLE currency (
    id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    entity_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    code VARCHAR(255),
    name VARCHAR(255),
    description VARCHAR(255),
    denomination_code VARCHAR(255),
    denomination_name VARCHAR(255),
    denomination_description VARCHAR(255),
    denomination_units integer,
    status VARCHAR(255)
);
```

DDL of currency_pair

```
CREATE TABLE currency_pair (
    id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    entity_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    base_currency_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL REFERENCES currency(entity_id),
    quote_currency_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL REFERENCES currency(entity_id),
    status VARCHAR(255),
);
```

And my entity classes are as follows:-

Currency Entity-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "currency")
public class Currency implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String entityId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String denominationCode;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String denominationName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String denominationDescription;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer denominationUnits;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String mask;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String status;

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

Currency Pair entity -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "currency_pair")
public class CurrencyPair implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String entityId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "base_currency_id", referencedColumnName = "entity_id")
    private Currency baseCurrency;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "quote_currency_id", referencedColumnName = "entity_id")
    private Currency quoteCurrency;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String status;

    /* Getters and setters */
}
```

`base_currency_id` and `quote_currency_id` in `currency_pair` table refers to non primary key column `entity_id` in `currency` tables.

When I am starting my springboot app it gives following error -

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with
>   logical name: **entity_id** in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(currency) and
>   its related supertables and secondary tables  at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:832)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:256)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:101)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1827)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1771)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1658)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]   ... 95 common frames
>   omitted

**note: I cannot change the ddl queries, so what can I do to fix the entity classes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have `referencedColumnName = "entity_id"` in `CurrencyPair` which has a relation with Currency. *In Currency, the name is entityId which doesn't match with entity_id.* You can add *name attribute* as follow in `Currency`

Change

```
@NaturalId
@Column(nullable = false)
private String entityId;
```

To

```
@NaturalId
@Column(name = "entity_id", nullable = false)
private String entityId;
```

Comment: applied your suggestion, now it can't find the logical column entityId in stead of entity_id

Comment: Also, change @Column(nullable = false) in CurrencyPair with @Column(name = "entity_id", nullable = false)

Comment: Also, refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351524/unable-to-find-column-with-logical-name

Comment: The second error was originating from another entity class. I will delete update 1 and 2, so that I other users wont get confused

Comment: @Bopsi yes, it will be good for future readers and thanks for accepting answer

Answer (score 1):

Can not find column `entity_id` because it is defined in `Currency` table as `entityId`

You can fix it by adding `name` attribure to `entityId` column on `Currency` class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "currency")
public class Currency implements Serializable {

    // ...

    @NaturalId
    @Column(name="entity_id", nullable = false)
    private String entityId;

    // ...
```

Comment: applied your suggestion, now it can't find the logical column entityId in stead of entity_id